# How to set seaborn color palette for multiple categories?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am passing a pandas dataframe to be plotted with `pd.scatterplot` and want to use the `'bright'` color palette. The color is to be determined by values in an integer Series I pass as `hue` to the plotting function.

The problem is that this only works when the `hue` Series has only two distinct values. When it has only one ore more than 2 different values, the plotting defaults to a beige-to-purple color palette.

When setting the color palette using `sns.set_palette('bright')` everything happens as described above. But when I do `palette='bright'`inside the plotting function call (**and n_classes is != 2**) I get an explicit Value Error thrown:

```py
ValueError: Palette {} not understood
```

Here is the code for reproducing:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_palette('bright')        # first method

n_classes = 3

a = np.arange(10)
b = np.random.randn(10)
c = np.random.randint(n_classes, size=10)

s = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B':b, 'C': c})

sns.scatterplot(data=s, x='A', y='B', hue='C')
plt.show()
```

For the second method simply change the scatterplot call to

```
sns.scatterplot(data=s, x='A', y='B', hue='C', palette='bright')
```

Is there a way to get multiple hue levels in the palette I want? Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the number of colors

Something like that.

```
sns.scatterplot(data=s,
                x='A',
                y='B',
                hue='C',
               palette=sns.color_palette('bright', s.C.unique().shape[0])
               )
```

Comment: Solves my problem but this is a workaround. After all, this example given in the seaborn tutorial works just fine:
`sns.set_palette('bright')`
`tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")`
`sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", data=tips)`

Comment: Found issues #s [1722](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1722) and [1653](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1653) on the seaborn issue tracker that seem to hail from the same source problem. Another way to solve this is passing hue values that cannot be cast to bool or numerical.